# Registering RAPI program with ActiveSync?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, activesync, rapi

I'm trying to write a program which will run when a Windows Mobile device is connected, according to [Microsofts documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa922038.aspx) to do that we have to:

> If you want your RAPI application to automatically execute when a
>   Windows Mobile device connects to the desktop computer, do not put
>   your application in StartUp or allow it to autorun. Instead, register
>   it to be automatically run by ActiveSync upon device connection. For
>   more information, see MSDN.

How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a registry value at

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows CE Services\AutoStartOnConnect

source:
http://pocketnow.com/tweaks-hacks/how-to-automatically-start-a-pc-application-on-device-connect-disconnect

Comment: thanks! I'm not sure why microsoft didn't write what they meant right there.